How to get user IP with Nginx in FastAPI?
request.client.host doesn't work (it gives Docker IP).
Code from GitHub doesn't help too (locally it works):
@app.get('/')
def index(real_ip: str = Header(None, alias='X-Real-IP')):
    return real_ip

The Nginx config:

Also I've found this answer on GitHub:
from starlette_context import middleware, plugins
app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    middleware.ContextMiddleware,
    plugins=(
        plugins.ForwardedForPlugin(),
    ),
)


@app.get("/")
def hello():
    forwarded_for = context.data["X-Forwarded-For"]
    return {"hello": "world", "forwarded_for": forwarded_for}

But I haven't tried it yet. All I need is to get a user IP.

You cannot inject the header as a default value, it is evaluated only once. Get it inside the function.

Have you set the --proxy-headers and --forwarded-allow-ips flags, as described in this answer (see the original section)?

The relevant documentation and implementation can be found here and here, respectively.

@KlausD. This is how dependencies work in FastAPI, so this is the expected way to ask for the value of a specific http header. FastAPI will populate it properly for each request as required.

@MatsLindh but doesn't work in my case :)

@Ch1irxo17 Have you tried inspecting the request object to see all the headers and the ips? Have you tried the answers linked by Chris and the parameters? What is the actual result from the different things you've tried? Are you behind cloudflare/another proxy/etc., or is nginx exposed directly to the internet through its own ip? How does a request move through your stack?

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.
